# Cannot access vagrant vm from the host machine

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, virtualbox

I've set a vagrant virtual box with Puphpet which is running fine (in Ubuntu 14.04) and I'm able to connect to it via ssh. I've also used vagrant hostmanager to get the vm's IP automatically added to the hosts file.

This is the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   pcuser-HP-EliteBook-8470p

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters


## vagrant-hostmanager-start id: 2314dd30-24cf-4122-8779-8b755f5e6186
172.22.22.22    projectname.local
172.22.22.22    www.projectname.local
## vagrant-hostmanager-end

## vagrant-hostmanager-start id: c20d4d7f-3ada-4b2a-b142-e44826571754
192.168.56.101  machine1.puphpet
192.168.56.101  symfony.dev
## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

The problem is when I try to access the VM from the host either through the IP address or through the virtual host server name I've set (symfony.dev).

Either time it's unable to connect to it, although I've pinged the machine IP from the host and it's responding fine.

At first I didn't have the vagrant hostmanager installed and just added the IP and the virtual host server name (symfony.dev) manually to the hosts file but it wasn't able to connect.

I've checked the settings in config.yaml file and they all seem to be fine:

```
vagrantfile:
target: local
vm:
    provider:
        local:
            box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
            box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
            box_version: '0'
            chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
            virtualizers:
                virtualbox:
                    modifyvm:
                        natdnshostresolver1: false
                    showgui: 0
                vmware:
                    numvcpus: 1
                parallels:
                    linked_clone: 0
                    check_guest_tools: 0
                    update_guest_tools: 0
            machines:
                vflm_zaw8al7jczu3:
                    id: machine1
                    hostname: machine1.puphpet
                    network:
                        private_network: 192.168.56.101
                        forwarded_port:
                            vflmnfp_67om22p4f0j3:
                                host: '5608'
                                guest: '22'
                    memory: '1024'
                    cpus: '1'
    provision:
        puppet:
            manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
            module_path:
                - puphpet/puppet/modules
                - puphpet/puppet/manifests
            options:
                - '--verbose'
                - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
    synced_folder:
        vflsf_y5mnuhi3ihqh:
            source: ./
            target: /var/www
            sync_type: nfs
            smb:
                smb_host: ''
                smb_username: ''
                smb_password: ''
                mount_options:
                    dir_mode: '0775'
                    file_mode: '0664'
            rsync:
                args:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--archive'
                    - '-z'
                exclude:
                    - .vagrant/
                    - .git/
                auto: 'true'
            owner: www-data
            group: www-data
    usable_port_range:
        start: 10200
        stop: 10500
    post_up_message: ''
```

Do I need to change anything in the configuration or what am I missing or doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the VM did you check your web server is running correctly ?

Comment: I've started the server on the vm: php bin/console server:run

                                                                                       
 [OK] Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you start your server but its bound to 127.0.0.1 / localhost IP so its only accessible from the VM

you need to start it using the IP of the VM or the 0.0.0.0 IP. something like this should work

```
php bin/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Oh,now I see it was the local host.

I've started the server with the vm IP:

php bin/console server:run 192.168.56.101

                                                                                       
 [OK] Server running on http://192.168.56.101:8000                                     
                                                                                       
// Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: working with the IP is good also (specially in DEV mode) but would recommend using  0.0.0.0. please make sure to take time to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: The server is running (but still can't connect to symfony.dev in the browser) if I start it from the vm, but if I exit the vagrant machine and start it from the host it ends with an error

Comment: you need to start it from the VM. so if you access http://symfony.dev:8000 or http://192.168.56.101:8000 you still get an error ?

Comment: php bin/console server:run 192.168.56.101 -v
                                                           
 [OK] Server running on http://192.168.56.101:8000                                     
                                                                                       
  RUN  '/usr/bin/php5' '-S' '192.168.56.101:8000' '/
 [ERROR] Built-in server terminated unexpectedly.        

Shouldn't be able to access it from the host as well?

Comment: Yes, it's still unable to connect after a while attempting to.

Comment: but `Built-in server terminated unexpectedly` means your server do not start properly, even from the VM you cannot access it ?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine now. In the end I found out that it was a problem with the PuphPet package that I have installed. I discovered that apache was not installed on the virtual machine, although I have selected it in the package build on Puphpet GUI and it also appeared to be installed as per the config.yaml file.

Merci pour ton aide, Frederic Henri!